# Django Rest Framework With Only Function Response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I just want to make a simple API with DRF. The API going to get a "keyword" from URL, and that "keyword" will go to a function. And function response is going to be API response.

Simple Example:

```
def returnSomething(word):
    test_string = "This is a example sentence. "
    add_string = word
    test_string += add_string
    return test_string
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/langdetect/helloworld/

RESULT:

```
{
  response: This is a example sentence. helloworld
}
```

It's all easy. How can I make this? I read the doc but every example is making with Models, serializers etc. I don't have any models. I have only a function and the response data.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the [hello world example using Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view)?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu OP wants to use DRF, not bare Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want a bare [`APIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) if you want to use DRF's permissions and content type negotiation system yet still keep things simple:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class SomethingView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        word = request.data.get('word')
        return Response({'response': f'Example: {word}'})
```